# Array em ngFor retornando no console mas não na tela

Tags: angular

Estou tentando pegar um array de um arquivo json enviado pelo back. Antes estava obtendo o erro de Cannot convert Array to Object (onde ele esperava um array e recebia um objeto), e depois de algumas tentativas agora estou obtendo resposta undefined.

Meu component.ts:

```
      
  listCarros?:any[];

  getAll(){
    this.carrosService.getAll().subscribe(response=>{
      this.listCarros = response.carros;
       this.listCarros = Array.of(response)
      console.log(this.listCarros);
    },error=>{
      alert("erro"+error);
    }
    );
```

Meu ngFor:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let m of listCarros">
```

Meu service.ts:

```
 getAll():Observable<CarrosToArray>{
        return this.http.get<CarrosToArray>(`http://localhost:8080/carros`);
      }
```

Comment: Para que isso `this.listCarros = Array.of(response)`??

Comment: Pra converter em Array, antes dava problema que recebia um Objeto e dava erro.

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver após uma minuciona análise. Meu array retornava dentro de um objeto com outros arrays (outras informações da requisição), e o ngFor quer só um array. Então no meu ts eu acessei o array pelas camadas dele até chegar no que eu quero:

```
  getAll(){
    
  this.carrosService.getAll().subscribe(response=>{


      this.listCarros = Array.of(response)
      this.directlyAcessListCarros = this.listCarros[0].content
      
    })

  }
```